# In Pandas, how to filter against other dataframe with Multi-Index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filter

I have two dataframes. The first one (df1) has a Multi-Index A,B.
The second one (df2) has those fields A and B as columns.

How do I filter df2 for a large dataset (2 million rows in each) to get only the rows in df2 where A and B are not in the multi index of df1

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,4),(2,3,4),(2,3,1)], 
                    columns=('A','B','C')).set_index(['A','B'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(7,7,1,2,3),(7,7,1,2,4),(6,6,1,2,4),
                    (5,5,6,3,4),(2,7,2,2,1)], 
                     columns=('X','Y','A','B','C'))
```

df1:

```
     C
A B   
1 2  3
  2  4
  2  4
2 3  4
  3  1
```

df2 before filtering:

```
   X  Y  A  B  C
0  7  7  1  2  3
1  7  7  1  2  4   
2  6  6  1  2  4
3  5  5  6  3  4
4  2  7  2  2  1
```

df2 wanted result:

```
   X  Y  A  B  C
3  5  5  6  3  4
4  2  7  2  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `MultiIndex` in `df2` by `A,B` columns and filter by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with `~` for invert boolean mask with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df2[~df2.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(df1.index)]
print (df)
   X  Y  A  B  C
3  5  5  6  3  4
4  2  7  2  2  1
```

Another similar solution with [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df = df2[~pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2['A'],df2['B']]).isin(df1.index)]
```

Another solution by @Sandeep Kadapa:

```
df = df2[df2[['A','B']].ne(df1.reset_index()[['A','B']]).any(axis=1)]
```